# Dynamically display the measures based on filter value in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I had a requirement where i have to display measures based on a filter created on Dimension value.
For eg

```
Dimension Filter Value Dropdown  --> Value1, Value2, Value3
Measures --> Measure1, Measure11, Measure2 Measure21, Measure22, Measure3
```

When I select

```
Case 1 : 
Filter -> Value1
Measure To display -> Measure1, Measure11

Case2 :
Filter -> Value2
Measure To display -> Measure2, Measure21, Measure22

Case3:
Filter -> Value3
Measure To display -> Measure3
```

I am new to tableau development and last few days i started using this . I googled few and found one resource in the below link
[Choose Measures dynamically](https://www.ryansleeper.com/how-to-let-users-choose-measures-and-dimensions-in-tableau/)

But in the above link they shown based on filter value they display only one measures not multiple measures.
I need to display multiple measures based on filter value.

As Explained i followed the process but don't know how to include multiple measures in the below code in Calculate field

```
CASE [Filter Parameter]
WHEN “Value1” THEN Measure1, Measure11
WHEN “Value2” THEN Measure2, Measure21, Measure22
WHEN “Value3” THEN Measure3
END
```

Hope it is explained well, please let me know .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to both transpose your dataset and create a flag to be used as the filter value.

To transpose your data:

- Edit your data source
- Click the first column you want to transpose and then shift + click the last

[image]

- Click Pivot
- Now navigate to your sheet to work with the data

I'll create a field to just pull out the number for the 'MeasureN' string so it's easier to create the filter, but this isn't necessary.

[image]

Now I'll write the calculation to be used as a filter that mirrors the logic you shared.

[image]

Arranging the pills on the screen like this...

[image]

Hopefully provides you with the functionality you were looking for. Happy vizzing!